# Snap applications do not startup randomly

Tags: launcher, snap, top

There are some applications like firefox and chromium, spotify that are now recommended to be installed from snap. When I do that on ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 22.10, they randomly stop launching.

- Win-key for search bar
- type "chromium", select / click
- nothing happens
- check `top` or `htop`, I find no application of that name.
- randomly small "waiting wheel" instead of mouse pointer appears.
- nothing further happens.

I cannot fix this without logging out, ending session and restarting session.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Snaps are running in an environment - so you've got several layers around your application. My experience is that the desktop integration is mediocre at best (user interaction, fonts, themes, startup time) so I refrained from using snap altogether.